# async GET request with body from browser

Tags: javascript, axios, get, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

Ok, I know it's a bad idea and it shouldn't be done but for the sake of this question please assume there's no other way - I am given API endpoint that requires GET request with empty object as a body.

Is there a way to do async request from browser? 
I'm using `axios` library which uses `XMLHttpRequest` under the hood and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) says that `send` wipes the body when HTTP method is `GET`. 
I tried using native `fetch` but it gives me this error in browser:
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't.

[GET requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) can't have a request body, you can't make them have one. GET requests only retrieve data, they never send data.

An API that requires GET request with empty object as a body just doesn't work.

#### Edit:

Apparently, GET requests are allowed to have a body. Most implementations will ignore it or reject the request. But even if the server that provides your API allows a body, you can't use it:

From the spec about [`XMLHttpRequest#send`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#the-send()-method):

> Initiates the request. The optional argument provides the request entity body. **The argument is ignored if request method is GET or HEAD.** Throws an "InvalidStateError" exception if the state is not OPENED or if the send() flag is set.

From the spec about the [`Request` class](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) in the fetch API:

> If either init’s body member is present and is non-null or **inputBody is non-null**, and **request’s method is `GET` or `HEAD`**, **then throw a TypeError**.

That means that the answer to your question is still *No*.

Comment: hmmm when doing research I found that this is not *entirely* true - for example Elastic Search allows such case. So I believe this a grey area - standard doesn't directly forbids that.

Comment: btw: this is the spec: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1
all it says is "A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
   sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
   implementations to reject the request."

Comment: Yes, it seems you're right. But I don't think `XMLHttpRequest` or the fetch API will let you give it a body.

Comment: Actually its not completely correct, GET request "can" have a request body which can be processed at the server end.