# angular http get data

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

I am looking through how to use `HttpClient`'s get method and I don't see how I can pass data in my get request. I only see how to GET a url. What I mean by this is I would like to do something like this:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_nodes \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 604243c2-f9da-4f71-b356-a8e31608b45d' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "username" : "jack_list",
    "node_name" : "nodeToFind"
}'
```

I would like to pass in `json`, as shown above with the `curl -d` flag, to my request. All examples I see online simply do this:

`this.http.get("url_of_api")`, But what if I need to pass json into my request?

Comment: GET request don't normally have a body. If you need to send data with a GET, use request parameters. If it needs to be in the body, youprobably want t POST or a PUT.

Comment: OK. Thanks. out of curiosity why is this non-standard way of using GET? From what i am getting i should pass parameter using the url of my GET request? What advantage does this give us over passing using parameter in the fashion i am trying to?

Comment: The advantage is that it respects the HTTP protocol: GET requests are not supposed to have a body. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body for a more detailed answer. So the advantage is the same as, let's say, not driving a car that is 8 meters large: the roads are not designed for such cars, and you're supposed to respect the rules.

Answer (score 2):

**HttpClient setup:**

Before you start working with `HttpClient` in Angular. You need to import `HttpClientModule` to your `AppModule`.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Everywhere where you want to use `HttpClient` you need to Inject it into `constructor`

`constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}`

**GET:**

For get the method can look something like this. In this example the request URL will look like this `http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_nodes?username="jack_list"&nodename="nodeToFind"`

```
const data = {
"username" : "jack_list",
"node_name" : "nodeToFind"
};
const httpOptions = {
  params: data,
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Postman-Token': '604243c2-f9da-4f71-b356-a8e31608b45d',
    'Cache-control': 'no-cache'
  });
this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_nodes', httpOptions);
```

**Post:**

For post the method will be very similar you just need to add your data there

```
const data = {
"username" : "jack_list",
"node_name" : "nodeToFind"
};
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Postman-Token': '604243c2-f9da-4f71-b356-a8e31608b45d',
    'Cache-control': 'no-cache'
  });
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_nodes', data, httpOptions);
```

Comment: `this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_nodes', data, httpOptions);` produces error "Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3."

Comment: I am sorry there is mistake. I have updated the answer.

Comment: but now it is a POST, OP is asking for GET which I don't think is possible.

Comment: I have updated it again and added sending data with QueryParams that's the only way if I am alright. Both examples should now do the same.

Answer (score -1):

GET requests don't typically contain a request body. You have to encode them into the URL.

For example:

JSON representation of request "data":

```
{
    "baz": "qux",
    "wotsit": [
       1,2,'three',
    ]
}
```

Equivalent GET request:

```
GET /foo/bar?baz=qux&wotsit[]=1&wotsit[]=2&wotsit[]=three
```

I've [implemented a helper function in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50651665/237955) that will encode your complex object into a series of GET parameters.

Comment: If the curl command the OP shows works then the server may be expecting the json data in the request body even though it is highly un-standard

Answer (score -1):

The high level `HttpClient.get()` doesn't offer request body parameter because a `GET` with a body is non standard, you sould be able to use `HttpClient.request()`. Note you may have to also wrap `data` in `JSON.stringify()` havn't tested.

```
const data = {
  "username": "jack_list",
  "node_name": "nodeToFind"
};
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json ');
headers.set('Postman-Token', '604243c2-f9da-4f71-b356-a8e31608b45d');
headers.set('cache-control', 'no-cache');
const req = new HttpRequest('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_nodes', data, { headers });
this.http.request(req).subscribe(res => {
  // do with res
});
```

update:

It seems the browser won't let you do this.
[async GET request with body from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550863/async-get-request-with-body-from-browser)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET

So my updated answer is this is impossible.